# XLST move descendant elements to highest level

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, flatten

Given an XML with the following structure:

```
<Sample>
  <Version>6</Version>
  <Date>2012-05-11</Date>
  <Header>
    <CreatedDate>2015-12-02</CreatedDate>
    <CreatedTime>10:31:42</CreatedTime>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <Group>1</Group> 
    <Type>1</Type>
    <Protocol>1</Protocol>
    <MessageHeader>
      <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </MessageHeader>
    <TransactionHeader>
      <ReportPeriodStartDate>2002-04-01</ReportPeriodStartDate>
      <ReportPeriodEndDate>2015-11-30</ReportPeriodEndDate>
    </TransactionHeader>
    <Episode>
      <Person>
        <General>
          <Verified>
            <Status>02</Status>
            <Identifier>001</Identifier>
            <PersonName>
              <Name>
                <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
                <Surname>Bar</Surname>
              </Name>
            </PersonName>
            <Address>
              <AddressLine></AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
            </Address>
          </Verified>
        </General>
      </Person>
      <Session>
        <Input>
          <StartDate>2015-10-31</StartDate>
          <StartTime>17:15:00</StartTime>
        </Input>
        <Output>
          <StatusCode>8</StatusCode>
          <LocationCode>9</LocationCode>
        </Output>
      </Session>
    </Episode>
    <MessageTrailer>
      <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </MessageTrailer>
  </Message>
  <Trailer>
    <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</Sample>
```

Is it possible to flatten the XML structure so that all elements in the Message element are at the same level, like below.

```
<Sample>
  <Version>6</Version>
  <Date>2012-05-11</Date>
  <Header>
    <CreatedDate>2015-12-02</CreatedDate>
    <CreatedTime>10:31:42</CreatedTime>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <Group>1</Group> 
    <Type>1</Type>
    <Protocol>1</Protocol>
    <!-- <MessageHeader></MessageHeader> -->
    <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
    <!-- <TransactionHeader></TransactionHeader> -->
    <ReportPeriodStartDate>2002-04-01</ReportPeriodStartDate>
    <ReportPeriodEndDate>2015-11-30</ReportPeriodEndDate>
    <Episode></Episode>
    <!-- <Person></Person> -->
    <!-- <General></General> -->
    <!-- <Verified></Verified> -->
    <Status>02</Status>
    <Identifier>001</Identifier>
    <!-- <PersonName></PersonName> -->
    <!-- <Name></Name> -->
    <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
    <Surname>Bar</Surname>
    <!-- <Address></Address> -->
    <AddressLine></AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
    <!-- <Session></Session> -->
    <!-- <Input></Input> -->
    <StartDate>2015-10-31</StartDate>
    <StartTime>17:15:00</StartTime>
    <!-- <Output></Output> -->
    <StatusCode>8</StatusCode>
    <LocationCode>9</LocationCode>
    <!-- <MessageTrailer></MessageTrailer> -->
    <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
  </Message>
  <Trailer>
    <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</Sample>
```

The elements which are commented out are not necessarily needed but could be kept if it makes it more simple.

I am looking for something generic which could be reused regardless of the XML structure. My thoughts are that the style sheet would be based on the identity template and would check if there are any descendants for elements, where those elements which have no descendants would be output.

Comment: "*I am looking for something generic which could be reused regardless of the XML structure.*" A generic stylesheet to flatten the XML structure  would also remove the Header, Message and Trailer wrappers.

Comment: Perhaps not that generic. Generic in the sense that the targeted element to flatten could have multiple levels to it.

Comment: I am afraid that's too vague for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSLT

The following XSLT flattens all of the "leaf" nodes found under each `<Message>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- XSLT identity transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match child elements of <Message> -->
    <xsl:template match="Message/*">
        <!-- select "leaf" elements (elements without child elements) -->
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output

```
<Sample>
    <Version>6</Version>
    <Date>2012-05-11</Date>
    <Header>
        <CreatedDate>2015-12-02</CreatedDate>
        <CreatedTime>10:31:42</CreatedTime>
    </Header>
    <Message>
        <Group>1</Group>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Protocol>1</Protocol>
        <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
        <ReportPeriodStartDate>2002-04-01</ReportPeriodStartDate>
        <ReportPeriodEndDate>2015-11-30</ReportPeriodEndDate>
        <Status>02</Status>
        <Identifier>001</Identifier>
        <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
        <Surname>Bar</Surname>
        <AddressLine/>
        <AddressLine>Street</AddressLine>
        <AddressLine>Town</AddressLine>
        <AddressLine>City</AddressLine>
        <StartDate>2015-10-31</StartDate>
        <StartTime>17:15:00</StartTime>
        <StatusCode>8</StatusCode>
        <LocationCode>9</LocationCode>
        <MessageReferenceNumber>1</MessageReferenceNumber>
    </Message>
    <Trailer>
        <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
    </Trailer>
</Sample>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--For any element that is a descendant of Message and has a child element, 
        generate a comment and then process it's children-->
    <xsl:template match="Message//*[*]">
        <xsl:comment>&lt;<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>>&lt;/<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>></xsl:comment>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```